# Menu not hiding properly for mobile view in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day all, I'm trying to make a left sided menu with bootstrap. I used jQuery to toggle menu show/hide for the Button click. Everything is working fine for Desktop view. But in mobile view, the Button is not beside the menu like the image below.

**Desktop View**
[image: Desktop View]

**Mobile View**

[image: Mobile View]

Here is my code,

```
<body>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav1').hide();
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#nav1').toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b style="font-size: 1.50em">Brand Name</b><br /><span style="font-size: .50em">Brand description</span></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp; Register</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> &nbsp; LogIn</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> &nbsp; LogIn</button>
            <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp; Register</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-home"></button>
    <ul id="nav1" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-sm-3">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Is there any wrong in my code? How can I get the same in mobile view just like Dekstop view? Your help would be much appreciable. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found it. Since I'm also working on mobile view then I should use `col-xs-3` instead of `col-sm-3`.

```
<ul id="nav1" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-xs-3">
```